# Advance Calculus Limit question

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to compute this limit without the use of L'Hopital's rule:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{4^{-1/x}+4^{1/x}}{4^{-1/x}-4^{1/x}}$$

I've been trying to multiply by the lcd and doing other creative stuff... anyone have any suggestions on theorems or techniques?

Comment: Why have you changed the title of the OP?

Answer (score 6):

Write the limit as 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{1+4^{-2/x}}{-1+4^{-2/x}}
$$
and use the fact that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{-2}{x}=-\infty.
$$
to find that the limit equals $-1$.

Answer (score 3):

A substitution can be helpful, as it transforms the expression into a rational function:

- Set $y=4^{\frac{1}{x}}$ and consider $y \to +\infty$

\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{4^{-1/x}+4^{1/x}}{4^{-1/x}-4^{1/x}}
& \stackrel{y=4^{\frac{1}{x}}}{=} & \frac{\frac{1}{y}+y}{\frac{1}{y}-y} \\
& = & \frac{\frac{1}{y^2}+1}{\frac{1}{y^2}-1} \\
& \stackrel{y \to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} & \frac{0+1}{0-1} = -1
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\dfrac{4^{-1/x}+4^{1/x}}{4^{-1/x}-4^{1/x}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\dfrac{4^{-2/x}+1}{4^{-2/x}-1}$$

Clearly as $x\to 0^+$, $2/x\to \infty$. Since the power of $4$ is $-2/x$, it must go to $0$. Effectively we have $\frac{0+1}{0-1}=-1$. Hence the required limit is $-1$.